# Write a function to let user calculate value of a function at an abitrary point

Tags: python, function, return-value

**Problem:** Write a function to let the user calculate the value of a function f(x) at an arbitrary point x = a

- Input: a
- Output: value of the function f at x = a

Apply to calculate the value of f(x)= sqrt(x-2) at x=4.

**My question:** I don't know clearly the meaning of this problem. If we want to calculate the value of a function, we can assign a value we need and put it in a function without defining a function like this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use something like [`eval`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval). You don't actually need to define a function in your code. Instead, you can put it in a string and pass it to `eval`.

Try something like this:

```
import math

a = int(input())
f = 'math.sqrt(x-2)'
x = a

print(eval(f))
```

You could change `f` to any function, or even read `f` from input as a string.

Comment: I think like the way you comment here but the requirements of the problem make me confused.

Comment: I see. I assumed your question was why not just define some function f as math.sqrt(x-2), and so I supplied this answer as an alternative.

Comment: Under the constraints of the problem as you've described it, I think you can just define some f and pass a to it, just print out `f(a)`

Answer (score 1):

You have `a` as input and `f(a)` as output, but the problem says define a function to apply `f` on `a`. So, instead of directly writing `f(a)` you write `eval_func(a)` that returns the same `f(a)`.

```
import math 

def eval_func(a):
    x = a
    return math.sqrt(x-2)
```

Run with input 4:

```
eval_func(4)
1.4142135623730951
```